# issue with using composer-php

Tags: php, composer-php

Every time when i want to use any commad like `self-update`, `install` or `update`composer generates this error:

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                   
The "https://getcomposer.org/version" file could not be downloaded: Failed to enable crypto                                                                                         
failed to open stream: operation failed
```

With composer install i get this error:

```
The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
https://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache   and may be out of date
```

I'm using php version 5.4.9 and my os is ubuntu 13.04 my composer version is :

```
Composer version 80499bb02418711b34bba59c1a6d8032429e5702 2013-12-06 12:32:19
```

This is driving me crazy please help!

This is a typical composer.json file for laravel:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.0.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "way/guard-laravel": "dev-master"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev"
```

}

Comment: can you paste your composer.json file

Comment: it seems that i can't do anything with https://getcomposer.org/ my php is `openssl` enabled i checked it with `php -m` there was an `openssl` extension.what should i do?

Comment: Can you try same command with sudo!?

Comment: This seems like a network connectivity issue.  Can you open those two urls in a browser?  Are you behind a proxy server?

Comment: in browser every thing is fine but with curl i get this error `curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to getcomposer.org:443`.the thing is there is no problem with `https:google.com` or other ssl protocols.

Comment: i have the same problem, actually many https based applications did not work: composer, bower, npm, git, ...
i don't know what is happening to https in our region, but a falback to http solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Use http as a workaround.

```
{
    "packagist": false
},
{
    "type": "composer",
    "url": "http://packagist.org",
    "options": {
        "ssl": {
            "verify_peer": "false"
        }
    }
}
```